# AMPscript Date Formating for French Language in HTML emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date, formatting

This puts today’s date in my HTML email:

`%%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%`

Any idea how to format this for FR?  I've tried doing this and it doesn’t work:

`%%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy","fr-CA")=%%`

I've tried using this:

`%%=Format(@today, "d MMMM yyyy")=%%`

But it returns this:
14 September 2017

So I need some way to get it to convert to French so that it reads:

`14 Septembre 2017`

I found the answer:
To format and display today’s date in English and French:

```
EN
%%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
FR
VAR @today 
SET @today = Now(1)
%%=FormatDate(@today,"dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA")=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and the answer you provided is correct.  Perhaps you have a formatting issue that is causing it to work incorrectly:

```
%%[
VAR @today 
SET @today = Now(1)
]%%
```

Then inside your email body place below where you want the date:

```
%%=FormatDate(@today,"dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA")=%%
```

OUTPUT: 14 septembre 2017

Another option to have it all set for a single AMPScript variable is below:

```
%%[
VAR @today 
SET @today = Now(1)
SET @frDate = FormatDate(@today,"dd MMMM yyyy",,"fr-CA")
]%%
```

Then inside your email body place below where you want the date:

```
%%=v(@frDate)=%%
```

OUTPUT: 14 septembre 2017