# Formatting Date and TIME in French

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date

I followed this question/Answer to format date in French:
[AMPscript Date Formating for French Language in HTML emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192254/ampscript-date-formating-for-french-language-in-html-emails/192259#192259)

Following this post, I would like to know how we should add the time to the date in French to get this result: "4 novembre 2019 à 16h30" ("à 16h30" means "at 4:30PM").

I tried the code below.
It seems to almost work, but I am not sure about the syntax, especially the "h" I add for "16h30"... it could be interpreted as the time/hour to display.

And also, for getting the MINUTES, I used mm (m in lowercase) but it seems that it displays the MONTH (11 / november) because when I refresh my tests, it never changes and the minutes stay on 11...!

I used the following code :

```
%%[
VAR @today 
SET @today = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now(1))
]%%
```

Inside the email body :

```
%%=FormatDate(@today,"d MMMM yyyy à HH'h'mm",,"fr-CA")=%%
```

Output :
4 novembre 2019 à 15h11
4 novembre 2019 à 16h11

Thank you

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
%%[
VAR @today 
SET @today = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now(1))
]%%

%%=FormatDate(@today,"d MMMM yyyy à ", "HH'h'mm","fr-FR")=%%
```

The FormatDate function takes up to 4 parameters. The parameter number 2 stands for the Date format pattern.
The Parameter number 3 stands for your Time format pattern.

I've just added a comma to separate the Date and Time patterns.

**Reference**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm

Comment: Thank you very much! it works perfectly :)

Comment: No worries Ludivine, don't forget to accept the answer so it will be easy for others to identify it..